# awk generate seq no vs day for all weekdays

Tags: awk

I need to generate index for all days using shell scripting and store the output in a file. Like below

```
1 Sun
2 Mon
3 Tue
4 Wed
5 Thu
6 Fri
7 Sat
```

Below is the command I'm using.

```
  awk ' BEGIN { yr=strftime("%Y",systime()) ; for(i=1;i<=13;i++) 
  { day=strftime("%a",mktime(yr " 1 " i " 0 0 0"));  
    if( day == "Sun" ) t++;
    if(t) print day
  } 
  }' | head -n 7 | awk ' { print NR, $0 } '
```

To me it looks lengthy and not efficient.
Is there a way to minimize the chaining and get it using single awk.

Comment: Must Sunday be day 1? What is your LC_IDENTIFICATION or locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {
   now = systime()
   for (i=1; i<=7; ++i) {
      wn = strftime("%u", now) + 1
      a[wn > 7 ? wn % 7 : wn] = strftime("%a", now)
      now += 86400
   }
   for (i=1; i<=7; ++i)
      print i, a[i]
}'

1 Sun
2 Mon
3 Tue
4 Wed
5 Thu
6 Fri
7 Sat
```

Comment: thank you.. good to know that changing "%a" to "%A" gives the expanded one..i.e Sunday and a flexible solution. ..````awk -v fmt="%A"````

Comment: @stack0114106 that and all the other format options are listed in the man page for the [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions).

Comment: @anubhava.. you are adding 86400 for jumping to next day.. how is that in James answer, he is just incrementing by 1 and it still works?

Comment: `86400` is no of seconds in a day and we are incrementing `systime()` returned value by a day every time

Comment: This approach is much more efficient because loop is iterated exactly 7 times where as `while(length(a)<7)` runs `450000` times :)

Comment: accepting ur answer as it is straight forward and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using `date` command

```
for i in {1..7}; do echo "$i $(date -d "last Saturday + $i days" '+%a')"; done
```

> 1 Sun
> 2 Mon
> 3 Tue
> 4 Wed
> 5 Thu
> 6 Fri
> 7 Sat

Index provided by `nl`command (adding just for fun)

```
for i in {0..6}; do date -u -d "last Sunday + $i days" '+%a'; done | nl -nln
```

> 1       Sun
> 2       Mon
> 3       Tue
> 4       Wed
> 5       Thu
> 6       Fri
> 7       Sat

Letting `date` set the day index

```
for i in {1..7}; do date -d "last Saturday + $i days" '+%u %a'; done | sort -k 1,1
```

> 1 Mon
> 2 Tue
> 3 Wed
> 4 Thu
> 5 Fri
> 6 Sat
> 7 Sun

Comment: Index changed in your second answer

Comment: yes, it's an alternative using the day index provided by `date`. Was the first option I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Bruteforcing it with GNU awk:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    a[1]                                           # init a as an array
    while(length(a)<7)                             # keep going until 7 entries
        a[strftime("%w",i)+1]=strftime("%a",i+=1)  # increase i+=1 value if needed

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"           # array traversal order
    for(i in a)                                    # once 7 found
        print i,a[i]                               # output
}'
```

Output:

```
1 Sun
2 Mon
3 Tue
4 Wed
5 Thu
6 Fri
7 Sat
```

Basically start from epoch 0 s and keep hashing until the size of `a` is seven. Now `i+=1` (or `++i`) adds just one second per iteration for show-off but increase it to `i+=24*60*60` or such.

Comment: your answer is also flexible.. ````awk -v fmt="%A"```` and I get expanded ones..cool

Comment: ````for ( i in a)```` will it not shuffle the output

Comment: It will if not instructed otherwise. Fixed it.

Comment: James.. comparing urs and anubhava's answer.. im getting confused now.. can you explain ````i+=24*60*60```` by some other example..how it works..

Comment: Well, 24×60×60=86400 which is the (average) number of seconds per day. Excluding leap seconds and DST jumping 86400 seconds forward you will land on the next day. My "brute force method" will hash `a[weekday number related to i]="weekday related to i"` and will keep doing it until there are seven entries in `a[]`. As long as the `i` is in the same sync on the left and right sides of the `=` in `a[...i...]=...i...` the array will be correct. The size of `n` in `i+=n` defines the time it takes to fill the `a` and 86400 is optimal (considering no leap seconds or DST around year 0—or year 1?).

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for `strftime()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        print i, strftime("%a",(i+3)*86400)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
1 Sun
2 Mon
3 Tue
4 Wed
5 Thu
6 Fri
7 Sat
```

The above just prints the day names starting at the first Sunday after the start of epoch time. In reality if I were doing this I'd just print the hard-coded numbers and day names but I understand from your comments that's not what you're looking for.

If the above isn't all you need then please edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: thanks Ed.. I just want to generate the output programmatically.. not hardcoding.

Comment: There's hardcoding no matter what you do (e.g. numbers 1 and 7) - do you really mean "just not hardcoding the names of the days"? If so please add that requirement to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ locale day abday
Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday
Sun;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat
```

```
$ locale abday | awk -F ';' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) print i,$i}'
1 Sun
2 Mon
3 Tue
4 Wed
5 Thu
6 Fri
7 Sat
```

`locale abday | tr ';' '\n'` would give the output without numbers

Or with seq+GNU date: `seq -f'Sun+%gday' 0 6 | date -f- +%a`

Comment: you can cut short ````awk -v RS=";" ' { print NR , $0 } ' ````

Comment: any way to get months using locale?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code.

Updated after Ed's comments to remove the hardcoding

```
  awk ' BEGIN { 
    yr=strftime("%Y",systime()) ; 
    for(i=1;i<=13;i++) 
    { 
      day=strftime("%u",mktime(yr " 1 " i " 0 0 0"));  
      if( day == 7 ) t++;
      if(t && t++<8 ) 
      print t-1, strftime("%a",mktime(yr " 1 " i " 0 0 0")); 
      # Increment t and check < 8
    } 
  }'
```

Original answer

```
  awk ' BEGIN { yr=strftime("%Y",systime()) ; for(i=1;i<=13;i++) 
  { day=strftime("%a",mktime(yr " 1 " i " 0 0 0"));  
    if( day == "Sun" ) t++;
    if(t && t++<8 ) 
    print t-1, day; # Increment t and check < 8
  } 
  }' 

1 Sun
2 Mon
3 Tue
4 Wed
5 Thu
6 Fri
7 Sat
```

Comment: That's more complicated and inefficient than it has to be and you said you didn't want any hard-coding but there's a "Sun" in there. It's also very hard to read - please run your code through `gawk -o-` so you can see how to format your code such that it makes the logic much clearer.